# Firefox adds extra width with padding

Tags: css, firefox, padding

I have a question regarding CSS in Firefox.

If i set a width of a floated div - lets say 200px - setting a padding-left to 10px will in Firefox add those extra 10px to the width. In IE that is not the case.

What can you do to prevent Firefox from adding the extra width to the div?

Comment: Always, but ALWAYS design your layouts in a standards compliant browser like FF and Chrome.  Then go back and figure out the places IE messes things up.

Comment: What you have there is IE in quirks mode.  FF is presenting the CSS correctly using the "box model."  Learn about the box model here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp  You may want to ask another question with your code in it, we can help you get it shored up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not firefox that's the problem, it's IE.

IE does not perform to standards, there are a few tricks to this but they are all a pain in the ass: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

The easiest way is to include a valid strict doctype tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Then just rewrite the css for the standards-compliant box model

[More doctypes here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_DOCTYPE.asp)

Comment: Correct but new web pages should always use the strict doctype.

Comment: You *said* strict but wrote up transitional.

Answer (score 4):

By default, box-sizing is set to content-box in mozilla and border-box in IE.

by using:

```
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

in your style's you can set box sizing of mozilla, safari and opera to border-box too.

for more information check:
http://www.css3.info/preview/box-sizing/